# Basic C Bitwise Operations Example

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
int sampleVariable; // declared and initialized and used elsewhere

if (sampleVariable & 2)
     someCodeIwantExecuted();
```

So if i wanted to manually manipulate sampleVariable so that if statement to evaluate as true and someCodeIwantExecuted() to execute I would do the following ?

```
sampleVariable |= (1 << 1);
```

Keep in mind I don't know what the value of sampleVariable is and I want to keep the rest of the bits the same. Just change the bit so that if statement will always be true.

Comment: Yes, you would write that like this. Perhaps without the parentheses.

Comment: You could also write `sampleVariable |= 2;` since that's how you're testing it. No reason to use two different notations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is fairly direct.

```
//  OP suggestion works OK
sampleVariable |= (1 << 1);

// @Adam Liss rightly suggests since OP uses 2 in test, use 2 here.
sampleVariable |= 2

// My recommendation: avoid naked Magic Numbers
#define ExecuteMask (2u)
sampleVariable |= ExecuteMask;
...
if (sampleVariable & ExecuteMask)
```

---

Note: when using the shift style as in `(1 << 1)`, insure that the *type* of `1` matches your target type

```
unsigned long long x;
x |= 1 << 60;  // May not work if `sizeof(int)` < `sizeof(x)`.
x |= 1ull << 60;
```

Further: Consider the advantages of `unsigned` types.

```
// Assume sizeof int/unsigned is 4.
int i;
y |= 1 << 31;  // Not well defined
unsigned u;
u |= 1u << 31;  // Well defined in C.
```